# Add and multiply values using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 products and wanted to multiply with quantity and add up both price along with tax and to show the final price of both added and multiplied values I tried doing using jQuery but I am unable to multiply and add up both values can any one help me out

Here is the code for it:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('#sticker01').on('keyup', function() {
  var sticker_01 = $('#sticker01').val();
  var oldval = parseInt($('#order_total').text());
  
  var total_val = (sticker_01 * 8 +1.30)  +  oldval;
  $('#order_total').html(total_val);
 });
});

$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('#sticker02').on('keyup', function() {
  var sticker_02 = $('#sticker02').val();
  var oldval = parseInt($('#order_total').text());
  
  var total_val = (sticker_02 * 2 + 1.30)  +  oldval;
  $('#order_total').html(total_val);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>MadEnoughToPayAttention Bumper Sticker</label>
  <input type="number" name="bumper_sticker_01_qty" id="sticker01">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>ChangeNotHope Bumper Sticker</label>
  <input type="number" name="bumper_sticker_02_qty" id="sticker02">
</div>

<div class="order_total">
  <span>Order Total : $<div id="order_total">0.00</div></span>
</div>
```

Comment: put your fiddle in the post, not in comment

Comment: I am trying to but getting error i don't know why that is why i placed in comment

Comment: jsfiddle is not working

Comment: You are including whole `<script>` tag. That is not how you include a library. **Just add the URL only**. **[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6d0je49h/1/)**. Also, include the code in your question with a working FIddle link.

Comment: Please do not try to get past posting a fiddle link without code, there isn't much code there. Can be easily made into a snippet.

Comment: okay wait let me update

Comment: fiddle is working now please check

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek okay thank you next time i will be carefull

Comment: Something appears to be happening, note it will be triggered only on key up. You will need to type in the number with the keyboard.

Comment: `sticker_01, sticker_02` should have `parseInt()`. \

Comment: I did but when I make first value back to zero the calculation does not effect by removing older one if i type in 2 in first box and 4 in second box result is okay and when i change the first value from 2 to 1 it adds up and dose'nt remove the previously added calculation did you noticed this bug

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek yes i am typing  in with keyboard

Comment: can anyone here to help me out

Answer (score 0):

Here is a less verbose solution to your issue with minor changes to the ***HTML*** and a complete overhaul of the ***Javascript***.

**HTML:**

I added the **`min`** attribute and set its value to **0** to prevent the *input spinners* from selecting negative values in both the **sticker01** and **sticker02** elements.  I also set the **order_total** input to **`disabled`** as this is the calculation field which will get its value from the inline *Javascript*.  These udpates are cosmetic and play no roll in the structural performance your *app*.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>MadEnoughToPayAttention Bumper Sticker</label>
  <input type="number" name="bumper_sticker_01_qty" min="0" id="sticker01">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>ChangeNotHope Bumper Sticker</label>
  <input type="number" name="bumper_sticker_02_qty" min="0" id="sticker02">
</div>

<div class="order_total">
  <span>Order Total : $
    <input type="text" name="bumper_sticker_total" id="order_total" disabled>
  </span>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

Here you can implement an anonymous function to handle the events **`.keyup()`** and **`.change()`** and use a delegated event on the input elements.

```
$('input').on('change keyup', function() {
  sticker_01 = $('#sticker01').val(),
  sticker_02 = $('#sticker02').val(),
  total_val = $('#order_total');

  if ((sticker_01) > 0 && (sticker_02) == 0) {
    total_val.val(((sticker_01) * 8 + 1.30).toFixed(2));
  } else if ((sticker_02) > 0 && (sticker_01) == 0) {
    total_val.val(((sticker_02) * 2 + 1.30).toFixed(2));
  } else if ((sticker_01) > 0 && (sticker_02) > 0) {
    total_val.val(((((sticker_01) * 8 + 1.30) + ((sticker_02) * 2 + 1.30)).toFixed(2)));
  } else {
    total_val.val('');
  };
});
```

That's everything you need.  Here is a sample **Code Snippet** for your review.

```js
$('input').on('change keyup', function() {
  sticker_01 = $('#sticker01').val(),
    sticker_02 = $('#sticker02').val(),
    total_val = $('#order_total');

  if ((sticker_01) > 0 && (sticker_02) == 0) {
    total_val.val(((sticker_01) * 8 + 1.30).toFixed(2));
  } else if ((sticker_02) > 0 && (sticker_01) == 0) {
    total_val.val(((sticker_02) * 2 + 1.30).toFixed(2));
  } else if ((sticker_01) > 0 && (sticker_02) > 0) {
    total_val.val(((((sticker_01) * 8 + 1.30) + ((sticker_02) * 2 + 1.30)).toFixed(2)));
  } else {
    total_val.val('');
  };
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>MadEnoughToPayAttention Bumper Sticker</label>
  <input type="number" name="bumper_sticker_01_qty" min="0" id="sticker01">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>ChangeNotHope Bumper Sticker</label>
  <input type="number" name="bumper_sticker_02_qty" min="0" id="sticker02">
</div>

<div class="order_total">
  <span>Order Total : $
    <input type="text" name="bumper_sticker_total" id="order_total" disabled>
  </span>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```